# Define distribution using percentile points

Tags: matlab, statistics, wolfram-mathematica, probability

In @Risk and Crystal Ball, we are allowed to define the probability distribution using percentile data. For example, we can define a log normal distribution just by inputting 3 data points, e.g. P10, P50 and P90 estimates. Then the software will come out with the PDF of the distribution. How is this actually done? Example in Matlab, Excel or Mathematica would be fine.

In the documentation, is not clearly stated how the software are doing it.

Comment: Appreciate it if someone can provide the workflow when using Matlab. Can we back calculate as per Mathematica solution below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a log-normal distribution derived from a normal distribution with mean = 1 and standard deviation = 0.5, calculating the 10th, 50th and 90th percentiles.

```
μ = 1;
σ = 0.5;

p[n_] := Quantile[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], n]

p10 = p[0.1]
```

> 1.43222

```
p50 = p[0.5]
```

> 2.71828

```
p90 = p[0.9]
```

> 5.15917

```
Show[
  Plot[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], x], {x, 0, 12}],
  Plot[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], x], {x, 0, #},
    PlotStyle -> None, Filling -> Axis] & /@ {p10, p50, p90},
  Epilog -> MapThread[Inset[#1, {#2, 0.025}] &,
   {{"p10", "p50", "p90"}, {p10, p50, p90}}]]
```

[image]

Now back-calculating `μ` and `σ` from only the percentiles as the OP's question requires.

```
Clear[μ, σ]

sol = Quiet@First@Solve[{
     Quantile[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], 0.1] == p10,
     Quantile[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], 0.5] == p50, 
     Quantile[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], 0.9] == p90}, {μ, σ}]
```

> {μ -> 1., σ -> 0.5}

Log-normal mean and variance:

```
Mean[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]] /. sol
```

> 3.08022

```
Variance[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]] /. sol
```

> 2.69476

Examining symbolic evaluation and definitions to understand the calculations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, quite simple to achieve using Mathematica